# Bug in Rendered Question?

Tags: bug, status-completed, specific-question, markdown

If you look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609276/listview-dataitem-shows-null) and have editing powers, you see the full text in the edit:

[image: Not Mucked Question in Edit Mode]

---

But if you look at it in Firefox 3.5, the question gets 'cut' off and the tags are moved to the previous line.

[image: Mucked Question w/ freehand circle]

---

Is this a bug?

Comment: This one's worth a bronze Bug Spotter badge for sure!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Known issue:
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12988/serverfault-cut-off-truncated-on-long-post

I thought we had all these cleaned up, though.

There was some work done early to try to find potential truncated posts, but everything I found was already cleaned up.